# which classifier would be better for scanned images?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, classification, feature-extraction

I am presently working with 500 of scanned images and have done feature extraction on them and I'm using the obtained offset values for classifying the images. I tried using k nearest neighbor classifier and want to know if i am proceeding in the right way?My main objective is to classify the images

Any help would be appreciated... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to classify images. Most of time I do it in 3 steps :

- Preprocessing (denoising, deskewing, etc.)
- Extracting features (colors, shapes, textures, SIFT, ...)
- Doing classification (kNN, SVM, Neural Network, ...)

Depending on the content of your images (natural images, biological images, document images, ...), you have to chose the features and then depending on the features you have to chose your classifier.

Be aware that supervised classification need some examples in order to learn.

Comment: Thank you... I'm done with the feature extraction and I want to know which classifier would give more accuracy for scanned images.That is,what is the best way to measure the accuracy

Comment: In order to measure performance of your classifier, you should use metrics such as [precision and recall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) or [F-score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) which is a mix of recall and precision.

Then, you should measure your performance with different classifiers (kNN with different k and SVM for example) and select the best classifier.

Answer (score 0):

KNN is one of the solutions.

What's the goal of your classification projects? For example:Do you need very high accuracy or recall? Do you need supervised or unsupervised solution.

Once you setup your goal, then you can do some related feature engineering and choose the right algorithm.